# On click of table view make it append string only on first click and not for another clicks in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

i am using table view to navigate the files on FTP.when user enters url i am appending the path for the clicked row in url field.It works fine for first click but as user clicks again double backslash gets added.I want to add backslash only for first click.Is it Possible to added check for another click?Hope i am clear with question.please help.`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *      listEntry;
    listEntry = [self.listEntries objectAtIndex:((NSUInteger) indexPath.row) - 1];
    NSString *dict=[listEntry objectForKey:(id) kCFFTPResourceName];
    NSLog(@"dict%@",dict);
    NSString *fvalue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/",dict];
    NSLog(@"%@",fvalue);

    NSString  *appendURl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.urlText.text,fvalue];

    self.urlText.text=appendURl;


}
```

Comment: what value is initially setting in `self.urlText.text` in `cellForRow` method?

Comment: urlpath/foldername/    and if folder contains subfolder it is url path/foldername//subfolder/

Comment: for subfolder i do not want to add backslashs i.e prefix backlash.

Comment: If you want to ignore further clicks one each item individually, you need to track each item's "already clicked state" somewhere (A list containing all clicked item's indexpaths, a struct containing the actual item and clicked state...). If you want only the first click fir the entire tableview a singe bool flag to be set and checked onclick will suffice. Since the actual problem is multiple backslashes however you should ensure that your paths are stored properly without leading and trailing backslashes so that you gain full control over where to place the slashes

Comment: If i remove leading backslash like "NSString *fvalue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",dict];" It works fine if i manually enter "/" at end  of url path if i do it programatically there is problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handled it by if else condition and using hasSuffix,problem got solved.`

```
if ([self.urlText.text hasSuffix:@"/"]) 
{
    appendURl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.urlText.text,fvalue];
}
else
{
    appendURl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",self.urlText.text,fvalue];
}
```